# Fractional derivative according to Fourier

Tags: fourier-transform, fractional-calculus

I am trying to show that $\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}e^{ikx}=(ik)^\alpha e^{ikx}$ when using the following equations for fourier transforms:
\begin{align}
g(k)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{ikx}dx \\
\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}f(x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(k)(-ik)^\alpha e^{-ikx}dk
\end{align}
Since in this case $f(x)=e^{ikx}$, $g(k)$ would be:
\begin{equation}
g(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}e^{ikx}dx
\end{equation}
I can't calculate $g(k)$, does anyone have any ideia on how i can do it?

Comment: I think that you should have two different $k$ so the integral should rather be 
$$
g_k(k') 
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx} e^{ik'x} \, dx
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i(k+k')x} \, dx.
$$